# Como apagar título do eixo em gráficos no R?

Tags: r, gráfico, plot

Estou fazendo várias regressões por uma mesma variável X e plotando juntas usando o comando `par(mfrow)` no `R`. Mas quero colocar somente um titulo no eixo do X no final de todos os meus gráficos. Eu já sei como colocar o título, no entanto não consigo apagar os os títulos das variável X gerado em cada gráfico. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Sua pergunta é clara, mas talvez colocar um exemplo de código e figura ajude a chamar a atenção de contribuidores.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode colocar a label do eixo x como vazia usando `xlab=""` dentro de `plot`.

Se quiser remover o espaço deixado, tem que alterar o parâmetro `mar`:

```
par(mar=c(3, 4, 4, 2)) #A ordem é: embaixo, esquerda, topo, direita
plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab="")
```